# Rails TimeZone in Production

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, timezone

My Server is USA West Coast but all the time that is recorded in the MySQL server should be done in UTC so that i can implement TimeZone for Users at the later date. Right now Configuring to Indian Timing.

Is there any configuration i need to do to get this working. i have added the following:

```
//application.rb
config.time_zone = 'UTC'
config.active_record.default_timezone :utc
```

Is there any other settings i need to do to tell rails that please save content in the UTC?

Comment: This may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226367/how-to-handle-mysql-timezone-in-script/28227116#28227116

Comment: Can you use the `TIMESTAMP` data type? (Do all the timestamps in your system lie between 1970 and 2037?) If you're already using that data type, your times are already stored in UTC.

Answer (score 1):

In rails application the time recorded in MySQL is automatically taken in UTC. What happens is when you give `config.time_zone = 'UTC'` in `application.rb`, the rails converts that time from UTC (stored in MySQL) to the timezone specified in `application.rb`. So I think there is nothing required to do that.

Hope this helps.