# How can i get today recent record in database by passing user timezone date?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-7

I tried but didn't get the success in this scenario.

actually data values are saving based on users timezone dates,

so i want dynamically passing some parameters to check and get the values from database. but problem is how can i pass parameter as user time to mysql query?

Per day if 10 records are there for User1, i want recent past one hour record based on user timezone date only.

```
$select = db_select('{emp}', 'e');
$select -> addField('e', 'name', 'name');
$select -> addField('e', 'date', 'date');
$select -> condition('e.name', $name);
$select->where('date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)');
$select -> orderBy('e.date', 'DESC')->range(0,1);
$subresult = $select -> execute()-> fetchObject();
```

in that query now() taking as a system time, in that place how can i pass user's time?

any help?

Comment: what orm or library does this use? Add that tag if appropriate.

Comment: we are using this in drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

See this. [How to handle MySQL timezone in script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226367/how-to-handle-mysql-timezone-in-script/28227116#28227116)

To store time data so it looks right to users in different time zones, you need to do several things.

First, ask each user to specify her timezone. [These are specified as strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) like `'America/New_York'` and `'Asia/Dili'`. Store that information as part of the each user's profile.

Next, each time you make a connection from your application to MySQL from your application, set the connection time zone with a command like this:

```
SET time_zone = users-time-zone-choice
```

Finally, always store time information in `TIMESTAMP` data types, rather than `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes. `TIMESTAMP` values are always converted from local time to UTC upon storage, and always converted back to local time upon retrieval.

So  `timestamp_column >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR` and similar queries work correctly.

`datetime_column >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR` won't work.

Then, the `NOW()` function will display in the user's local time. So will the contents of `TIMESTAMP` data items.     The contents of `DATETIME` and `DATE` objects will **not** display in users' local time; they are always stored and retrieved without respect to timezone.

It's best to set your server default timezone to UTC.

You can try this out; these commands should give you some interesting results.

```
set time_zone = 'Asia/Dili';
select @@time_zone, now(), utc_timestamp();
set time_zone = 'America/Phoenix';
select @@time_zone, now(), utc_timestamp();
set time_zone = 'Asia/Jerusalem';
select @@time_zone, now(), utc_timestamp();
```

Comment: Set the timezone to UTC and I have tried this one,but still taking server time only,not users time.